# Convert a string date from json to Java LocalDate

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8

I use spring boot and spring 4.

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {ServerApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I try to use Java 8 LocalDate.

In the json for the date i have

> birthdate: "1969-12-29"

On the server side for this field i have

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate birthdate;
```

I get this error

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple
>   type, class java.time.LocalDate] from String value ('1969-12-29'); no
>   single-String constructor/factory method

Edit

Dto send via ajax

```
public class LodgerInformationDto {
    private Long lodgerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate birthdate;
}
```

Controller Rest class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public LodgerInformationDto createLodger(@RequestBody @Valid final LodgerInformationDto lodgerDto) {
        return lodgerService.save(lodgerDto);
    }
```

with this dependencies: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.6.3

this line in the application.properties
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false

that work.

Comment: show the complete code please

Comment: I hope you recognize that your current solution is what I suggested. `@DateTimeFormat` does nothing in that case. Also, that property you added serves no purpose for the deserializing you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

[`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) is meant to be used with model attributes (command objects), not JSON bodies.

From your question,

> In the json for the date i have

it seems you are submitting the date as part of the request body, as JSON.

There is an entirely different process that handles JSON deserialization. Typically, that is a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` assuming you have Jackson on the classpath.

For this to work with Jackson, you'll need a `Module` that supports Java 8 types. There is [this one](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) and [this one](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310). These know how to deserialize JSON content into Java 8 date-time types.

You can use [`@JsonFormat`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) to provide a date format.

Comment: DateTimeFormat can be used on PathVariable, RequestBody... For the Java 8 type, i added Jsr310JpaConverters.class that the class who add the support in spring. Date is in a DTO.

Comment: @roberttrudel For `@PathVariable` sure. For `@RequestBody`, it depends on the underlying `HttpMessageConverter`. Jackson knows nothing about `@DateTimeFormat`. Your Jpa converter is just that, a JPA converter. There's nothing here that involves JPA.